# Stokes Theorem 4-dimensional volume

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $B(n,r)$ be the ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $volB(2,r)= \pi r^2$ and $volB(3,r)= \dfrac{4\pi r^3}{3}$. Show that $volB(4,r)= \dfrac{\pi^2 r^4}{2}$.

Hint: We know that $volB(4,r)= \int_{B(4,r)} dx~\wedge~dy~\wedge~dz~\wedge~dt$.Parametrize the ball $B(4,r)$ by

$$(x,y,z,t)=F(\sigma,\psi,\theta,\phi)=(\sigma\sin\psi\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sigma\sin\psi\sin\phi\sin\theta,\sigma\sin\psi\cos\phi,\sigma\cos\psi)$$

whit 
$(\sigma,\psi,\theta,\phi) \in ~[0,r] \times[0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi] \times [0, \pi]$. **Use the stokes theorem**.

Ps. Fixed $r>0$, we have $volB(n,r) \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @EricTowers, you're right, I made a small mistake writing.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @md2perpe This is a question of a test. My attempt to solve it is very similar to [this one](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~wshih/mathnotes/n-D_Spherical_coordinates.pdf). But I found it a very difficult way to do it during a test, I wonder if there is any other way ....